# Inserting multiple list into SQLite database using Python 3

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.4

I have multiple list and i would like to insert the data that is stored in the list into the sqlite database.

My insert statement is:
c.executemany("INSERT INTO admin(class, level, registerNo, ic, name) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (sclass, level, registerNo, ic, name))

But my error stated: 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 10 supplied.

Comment: Can you give example values for each variable in sclass, level, registerNo, ic, name?

Comment: Are you really sure that the exception was raised in this line, and that this is the code that actually got executed?